# Ninject for Asp.net Web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, ninject, ninject.web.mvc

I got this error when using Ninject with Web API, but it works with MVC Controller:

```
Type 'App.Web.Controllers.ProductController' does not have a default constructor
```

NinjectControllerFactory :

```
public class NinjectControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
    {
        private IKernel ninjectKernel;

        public NinjectControllerFactory()
        {
            ninjectKernel = new StandardKernel();
            AddBindings();
        }

        protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
        {
            return controllerType == null ? null : (IController)ninjectKernel.Get(controllerType);
        }

        public void AddBindings()
        {
            ninjectKernel.Bind<IProductRepository>().To<EFProductRepository>();
        }
    }
```

Global.asax.cs :

```
BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

            ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new NinjectControllerFactory());
```

ProductController :

```
   public class ProductController : ApiController
        {
            private IProductRepository repository;

            public ProductController(IProductRepository ProducteRepository)
            {
                this.repository = ProductRepository;
            }

            public IEnumerable<Product> GetAllProducts()
            {
                return repository.Products.AsEnumerable();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have overriden the `DefaultControllerFactory`. But this is used to instantiate ASP.NET MVC controllers (one deriving from `System.Web.Mvc.Controller`). It has strictly nothing to do with ASP.NET Web API controllers (the ones deriving from `System.Web.Http.ApiController`).

So basically what you have done here is dependency injection into ASP.NET MVC. If you want to use this for the Web API you may take a look at the following guides:

- http://www.strathweb.com/2012/05/using-ninject-with-the-latest-asp-net-web-api-source/
- http://www.peterprovost.org/blog/2012/06/19/adding-ninject-to-web-api/

Answer (score 2):

You should use the latest Ninject Web API package, which solves these problems already. See here: http://nuget.org/packages/Ninject.Web.WebApi.WebHost/

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `DependencyResolver` property of the `HttpConfiguration`. What you have done was for ASP.NET MVC and not ASP.NET Web API.

So get the NuGet package and set DependencyResolver:

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel();
// use kernel to register your dependencies
var dependencyResolver = new NInjectResolver(kernel);
config.DependencyResolver = dependencyResolver; // config is an instance of HttpConfiguration based on your hosting scenario
```